# How do I test if a player has an item with a custom name in inventory WITHOUT scoreboards?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to test if a player has an item named "sunny", and if they do to have it turn into a shulker box.
If you could include the shulker box having a torch named "sunny" that would be very much appreciated too.

The command I tried was this:

```
execute if entity @p[nbt={Items:[{id:"!minecraft:torch"}]},display:{Name:'{"text":"Sunny"}'}] run setblock ~ ~2 ~ minecraft:blue_shulker_box
```

But it said display option was not an option.

Answer (score 2):

```
/execute if entity @p[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:torch",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"Sunny"}'}}}]}] run setblock ~ ~2 ~ minecraft:blue_shulker_box
```

I tested this in-game and it works fine.

Comment: What about the custom name? The question had data for that, but you did not include any mention to it.

Comment: Blue Robin, I tried what you said but... 1 ExpertCoder14 is right... And 2, I need for it to test if the player has the item, not... Not having the item . Other than that though, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Anonymousperson I tested this out in game and it works! The command places a shulkerbox if the player has the torch named Sunny. Command: /execute if entity @p[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:torch",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"Sunny"}'}}}]}] run setblock ~ ~2 ~ minecraft:blue_shulker_box

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Thanks! I didn't see that. I did an edit on the command.

Comment: Thank you guys!

Comment: You're welcome, @Anonymousperson If the answer worked you can accept it to let others know this was the right answer.